# Is it possible to use material-ui button navigation with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have a web app that I'v designed with material-UI and as you can see below I'm using Button navigation for navigating through my basic landing page components.

```
<div className="footer">
  <BottomNavigation value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} className={classes.root}>
    <BottomNavigationAction label="signal" value="signal" icon={<ShowChart />} className={classes.content}/>
    <BottomNavigationAction label="hotlist" value="hotlist" icon={<HotList />} className={classes.content}/>
    <BottomNavigationAction label="analyze" value="analyze" icon={<PieChart />} className={classes.content}/>
    <BottomNavigationAction label="learn" value="learn" icon={<LibraryBooks/>} className={classes.content}/>
    <BottomNavigationAction label="dashboard" value="dashboard" icon={<PermIdentity/>} className={classes.content}/>
  </BottomNavigation>
  </div>
```

I've tried to use React-Router with these predefiend navigation component but that didn't work, is there any possible way to use Router with Button navigation of material-UI?
Button navigation article in material-UI
[ButtonNavigation API](https://material-ui.com/api/bottom-navigation/)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to use the `component` prop:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import BottomNavigation from '@material-ui/core/BottomNavigation';
import BottomNavigationAction from '@material-ui/core/BottomNavigationAction';

// ....

<BottomNavigation value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <BottomNavigationAction
        component={Link}
        to="/signal"
        label="signal"
        value="signal"
        icon={<ShowChart />}
        className={classes.content}
    />
</BottomNavigation>
```

(the `to` prop is for React Router's `Link` component)

This works with any Material-UI component that inherits from `ButtonBase`.

https://material-ui.com/api/bottom-navigation-action/

> ### Inheritance
>
> The properties of the ButtonBase component are also
>   available. You can take advantage of this behavior to target nested
>   components.

https://material-ui.com/api/button-base/

> ### Props
>
> `component` - The component used for the root node. Either a string to use a DOM element or a component.

Comment: If you need BottomNavigationAction to be shown as selected when you visit an url, you need to 1. get current location using `useLocation` from `react-router-dom` 2. give it to `BottomNavigation` with `value={location.pathname}` 3. give each `BottomNavigationAction` proper `value` prop, e.g. `value="/about"

Answer (score 10):

Just to add on to the great answer by @thirtydot , in case the user **types into the search and visits a particular webpage directly** (other than default) e.g. "www.yoursite.com/tab2", instead of clicking the 2nd button, this may cause a mismatch between the site that is showing and the BottomNav Button that is focused (usually the 1st button).

Here is what I did:
I used `window.location.pathname` to get the current path which is '/tab2' directly.
Here is my code for my particular use case....

```
function BottomNavBar(){
    const pathname = window.location.pathname; // in case user visits the path directly. The BottomNavBar is able to follow suit.
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(pathname);
    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    };

    return (
        <BottomNavigation value={value} onChange={handleChange} showLabels={true} >
          <BottomNavigationAction label="home" value="/" icon={<HomeIcon />} component={Link} to='/'/>
          <BottomNavigationAction label="resources" value="/resources" icon={<ResourcesIcon /> } component={Link} to='/resources'/>                
          <BottomNavigationAction label="Q&A" value="/qna" icon={<QnAIcon />}  component={Link} to='/qna'/>
          <BottomNavigationAction label="profile" value="/profile" icon={<ProfileIcon />} component={Link} to='/profile'/>
        </BottomNavigation>
      );
}
```

Comment: Read the answer by @thirtydot first.

Comment: @mcKindo No problem! Happy this helped

Comment: An add on. Instead of using window.location.pathname (as you have to parse it.. think of the case if the url is '/tab2/123' instead), I believe for CRA users, most likely you will be using react-router-dom. You should use that instead to get the path. 
`import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'`
or refer to this [other stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253277/react-router-v4-how-to-get-current-route) for other alternatives

Answer (score 5):

## 2023 complete answer

Building on @thirdydot's answer and @trashgenerator's comment, filling in all the remaining gaps.

If you want to hook up `BottomNavigation` with `react-router-dom` then you want the router to hold the single point of truth. This means to rely on `useLocation` instead of `useState` to store this aspect of your app's state and `Link` to change the state.

There's 3 steps to this:

1. Make sure you are inside the router context for `useLocation` to work (see below).
2. In `BottomNavigation` set `value={useLocation().pathname}` instead of `useState` and `onChange`.
3. In `BottomNavigationAction` use `component={Link}` and `to="/signal"` and set the `value` to that same path.

#### `src/components/RouterBottomNavigation.js`

```
import { useLocation, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BottomNavigation, BottomNavigationAction } from '@mui/material';
/* import icons */

export default function RouterBottomNavigation() {
  return (
    <BottomNavigation
      value={useLocation().pathname}
      className={classes.root}
    >
      <BottomNavigationAction
        component={Link}
        to="/signal"
        value="/signal"
        label="Signal"
        icon={<ShowChart />}
        className={classes.content}
      />
      <BottomNavigationAction
        component={Link}
        to="/dashboard"
        value="/dashboard"
        label="Dashboard"
        icon={<PermIdentity />}
        className={classes.content}
      />
    </BottomNavigation>
  )
}
```

How does this work? The location pathname now holds the state for your bottom navigation.

If it's `/dashboard` then your dashboard `BottomNavigationAction` is active, because it's value is also `/dashboard`.

And when you click a `BottomNavigationAction` that is also a router `Link`, you change the location pathname to the `to` value.

### On being inside the router comntext

And to be inside of the router context, you could place the `RouterBottomNavigation` next to the `Outlet`. For example:

#### `src/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import Root from "./routes/root";
import Dashboard from "./routes/dashboard";
import Signal from "./routes/signal";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "dashboard",
        element: <Dashboard />,
      },
      {
        path: "signal",
        element: <Signal />,
      },
    ]
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

#### `src/routes/root.js`

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

import RouterBottomNavigation from "../components/RouterBottomNavigation";

export default function Root() {
  return (
    <>
      <Outlet />
      <RouterBottomNavigation />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in new versions theres this property "LinkComponent" which lets you link directly to a  component that renders the page you want, very similar to previus answers:

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import BottomNavigation from '@material-ui/core/BottomNavigation';

import BottomNavigationAction from '@material-ui/core/BottomNavigationAction';

// ....

<div className="footer">
  <BottomNavigation value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} className={classes.root}>
    <BottomNavigationAction label="signal" value="signal" icon={<ShowChart />} className={classes.content} LinkComponent={Link} to={'/your-route'}/>
    <BottomNavigationAction label="hotlist" value="hotlist" icon={<HotList />} className={classes.content} LinkComponent={Link} to={'/your-route'}/>
    <BottomNavigationAction label="analyze" value="analyze" icon={<PieChart />} className={classes.content} LinkComponent={Link} to={'/your-route'}/>
    <BottomNavigationAction label="learn" value="learn" icon={<LibraryBooks/>} className={classes.content} LinkComponent={Link} to={'/your-route'}/>
    <BottomNavigationAction label="dashboard" value="dashboard" icon={<PermIdentity/>} className={classes.content} LinkComponent={Link} to={'/your-route'}/>
  </BottomNavigation>
  </div>
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoever is coming here as of September 2023, here is how I got it to work with nextjs link

```
             <BottomNavigationAction
                aria-label="go home"
                LinkComponent={Link}      // <--- this is next link
                icon={<HomeOutlined />}
                href={'/'} // <---------or build your own href
            />
```